# Admob - anuncios em videos

Tags: android, admob

Gente, to pensando em criar um app cuja forma de monetização seja aqueles anuncios em videos que o usuario assiste pra ganhar algo no app, sabe os rewards videos tipo o Angry Birds, na verdade, eu to pensando em alguns itens em que pra o usuario ganhar ele tem que assistir 1 ou 2 videos, ok.

Minha duvida é: 1º como faço pra saber se o usuario assistiu realmente o video? o admob tem algum metodo de retorno pra informar isso? Alguem conhece algum exemplo implementado, algum link ou video que explique?

E minha maior duvida é: sera que compensa? A gente não consegue encontrar nada a respeito de valores do admob!!! Tipo quanto eles pagam por cada click nos banners, por cada anuncio intersticial que é exibido, ou por cada anuncio nativo (igual aqueles do CM Lite), e principalmente quanto eles nos pagam por cada video que o usuario assiste??????? Alguem pelo amor de Deus pode me informar esses valores... onde tem essa tabela, porque eu não achei nada a respeito, inclusive o admob nem tem email de suporte >:[

Sei que bem relativo, mas to perguntando em media mesmo... porque preciso decidir se uso essa forma de monetização ou vendo cada item no inApp Billings, mas os videos é bem mas facil do usuario aceitar, comprar q é bom ninguem quer...

Por favor se alguem souber eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Eu te  aconselho a usar o Appodeal, Appodeal é um mediador que trabalha com varias networks e escolhe os anúncios que pagam mais, você pode escolher com quais network trabalhar ou simplesmente trabalhar com todas.
https://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation?framework=1&full=1&platform=1
A documentação explica sobres as recomeças, acho que vale a pena dar uma lida.

Aqui fala um pouco sobre os Rewards
https://blog.appodeal.com/blog/2016/09/15/rewarded-videos-irresistible-format/

Comment: ei @Wallace Roberto, esse Appodeal tem de instalar uma extenção do chrome, voce saberia me informar como eu faço pra configurar no braço? porque eu só uso o firefox.

Comment: então você tem que ter conta no admob.

Comment: Faz outra pergunta aqui no stack que detalho pra você como usar o appodeal

Comment: Oi, valeu pela dica. Fiz a pergunta aqui (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188000/usar-o-mediador-appodeal) se vc puder me ajudar, sou nova nisso e trabalho sozinha, como o @Armando Marques Sobrinho tb só uso firefox porem ja tenho a conta do admob. Esse mediador é usado junto com o admob? Como? Como eu disse sou nova nisso, é meu 1º app. :)