# usar o mediador Appodeal

Tags: android

Como usar o mediador Appodeal? Sou nova nisso, to tentando monetizar um app.

Alguem pode me descrever os passos?

Quanto eles pagam por cada video reward que é exibido? (Uma media pelo menos)

Comment: Precisa da extensão, não sei se tem ela no firefox no google crhome e Uc Browser eu sei que tem

Answer (score 1):

Vamos Começar , com a conta no admob e appodeal criada vá para este link https://www.appodeal.com/apps/new?apps_filter=0
preencha conforme seu app,certifiquese de colocar a opção android e lembrando que `Bundle ID` é o nome do pacote de seu aplicativo.
creat app-> escolha sua platoforma -> os tipos de propagandas -> se você escolheu banner na proxima pagina escolha se ele ficara no topo ou embaixo.
na proxima pagina aparecera as networks se quiser desativar alguma é só clicar nela, o processo sera mais lento se todas tiverem selecionadas mais nada fora do normal,
dpois você escolhe se quer mostrar propagandas que gerem mais lucro($$$) ou que tem melhores Reviews,
ná proxima pagina se você ativou o interstical tera duas opçoes escolha a que melhor te agrada, selecione se está usando proguard ou não, emfim a documentção.

neste ponto você irá precisar do google chrome uc browser  para instalar a extensão, Não sei se tem extensão para Firefox mais sem a extensão na tem como.
Quando a extensão estiver instalada clique nela, la tera os passos, vai clicando na ordem para fazer oque precisa, na opçao que tem o admob irá configurar sozinho não faça nada até acabar,
quando terminar clique na extensão de novo e termine o proceso que falta, vai aparecer uma  mensagem na pagina do admob feche ela pra continuar a conficuração.

quando estiver assim esta parte está pronto, caso não esteja refaça de novo a parte da extensão.
no ponto 3 faça o download do sdk `You can download Android SDK here.`.

Coloque isso no seu .Gradle 
`compile project(':cheetah-mobile-3.4.7')`
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'`
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'`

coloque isso no seu manifesto, não se esqueça das permissões! sabe como funciona o manifesto né?
https://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation?framework=1&full=1&platform=1#p_4

aqui um video de 2015 comparativo que mostra a diferença dos ganhos gerados entre os dois.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUQrCM_ClVQ.

aqui um video em ingles desatulazido de tudo que falei.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FB0T-Dsmo6c

aqui um video em português desatulazido de tudo que falei.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLReoaG30AI

Aqui um código pra você testar o anuncio com um banner em baixo.
só colar na atividade que quiser.

```
    String appKey = "Coloque aqui a chave appodeal do seu app";
    Appodeal.initialize(this, appKey, Appodeal.BANNER);
    Appodeal.show(this, Appodeal.BANNER_BOTTOM);
```

Comment: valeus @Wallace Roberto, pesquisei e nenhuma extensão para firefox foi encontrada, mas pelo que conversei no chat do appodeal eles só usam a extensão para fazer as modificações no admob e só uma unica vez, dai vou instalar o chrome aqui só pra isso e depois voltarei ao assunto contigo, blz, já tenho apps rodando com o admob, mas to precisando alavancar mais os ganhos deles.

Comment: Ta bom, to aguardando.